# How does the closure parameter works in Angular's $http Service?

Tags: angularjs, closures

I don't understand about the closure in the `success` method in Angular's `$http` Service. I know the overgiven `function(data){}` is a closure. But what is the outer function of that closure? 
Ans is in that outer function the `data` object inside?

```
$http.get( 'my/url' ).success( function( data ){
// I do something with data
});
```

Comment: Until we see the rest of the code we don't know the outer function or if there is one at all. A function is not a closure, it can create one.

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.get( 'my/url' ).success( function( data ){
// I do something with data
});
```

In this `function( data ){
    // I do something with data
    }` is more of a callback function passed to the promise resolve method.

In that `$http.get()` once the service resolves and returns data. If the promise is fulfilled, then from the promise the obtained response data is passed to registered callback function as argument.

So that you can access that data in your success callback. In case if it's an error, then the error object will be passed to the err callback as argument.

In your example, it's more of a callback function than a closure. The `data` object is passed as an argument to the anonymous callback function when the promise is resolved other than that it' not part of closure.

Comment: in the Angular documentation it's mentioned, that data (and status, header, and so on) are destructive representations of the response object from the ajax response. 
And these objects (data, ...) are overgiven to the then() method: the handler, that is triggered when the promise gets his status (fulfilled, rejected).
So success() and error() have access to these objects. Would you say, that success() and error() are closures into then()? If then() would return success() or error(), then these closures would be able to have further access to the variable scope into then(): data, status, etc.